# idea SQL dialect is not configured in mybatis

Tags: intellij-idea, mybatis, spring-mybatis

[SQL dialect is not configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utVo4.png)

this is mine mapper.xml,i want to clear Warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime you get the light bulb, if you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> / <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>↵</kbd> you will most often get a list of quick-fixes (or intentions). In this case you will should get an option to inject the language, or to edit the language injection settings. It's not clear what type of file you are editing in your screenshot (it's obviously some type of XML like markup). So I'm not 100% sure which quick fix (if any) will be available in that context.

You can also take a look at this SO answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30759243/1348743 -- of mine as it provides a lot more detail about other ways of configuring SQL dialects. Also look at the IntelliJ IDEA help documentation on [Using Language Injections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-language-injections.html).

Answer (score 1):

idea -> setting -> SQL dialect

[sql dialect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8iTX.png)

see the right column 'sql dialect',default value is 'Generic'.
change it to your own db name